# Alternatives to performing a logical NOT on Optional ifPresent() for clarity and readability

Tags: java, option-type

When I want to check against an `Optional` being empty I can use `ifPresent()`. This works fine but it can be misleading when trying to check if something is NOT present when an expression is also checking against `isEmpty()`.

For example:

```
if (!a.isPresent() && b.isEmpty() && c.isEmpty())
   return true;
```

If I read it quickly I think it's supposed to be `if true && false && false`. I have to always pay special attention to whether it's "if NOT present" rather than "if present".

I can of course write it like this:

```
if (a.isPresent() == false && b.isEmpty() && c.isEmpty())
   return true;
```

But that's horrible to my eyes.

I wish that `Optional` had an `isEmpty()` as in my mind I consider it in my mind as a collection of one but alas we do not.

Are there any alternative ways to write this such that the intent is obvious but it also reads well?

Comment: Write an `isEmpty(Optional)` method?

Comment: I did not use `==` to compare. I used `equals`, you know.

Comment: You are correct. I read `==` as `equals` in my head and missed the obvious comparison. A dangerous thing to do in Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you can write such a method yourself, but personally, I find this quite readable as well:

```
if (a.equals(Optional.empty()))
```

It clearly reads "if a is empty". I think this will solve the problem of "not seeing the little `!` operator" pretty well, since the expression becomes more wordy ad you will pay more attention to it naturally.

Comment: This is reasonable and reads well. A definite improvement. Thank you. :)